# Getting 'Potential leak of an object stored into...' despite using CFBridgingRelease()

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation, clang-static-analyzer

The following code makes Xcode's static analyser bark:

```
CFErrorRef accessControlError = NULL;
SecAccessControlRef accessControlRef = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
                                                                       kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                       kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked,
                                                                       kSecAccessControlUserPresence,
                                                                       &accessControlError);
if (accessControlRef == NULL || accessControlError != NULL) {
    NSString *fail  = CFBridgingRelease(CFErrorCopyDescription(accessControlError));// Bark!
    if (error != NULL) {
        *error      = [TSErrorHandler errorWithCode:TSErrorCodeKeychainACLCreateFailure failureReason:fail];
    }
    return NO;
}
attributes[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessControl] = (__bridge id)accessControlRef;
```

Profiling in Instruments does indeed indicate that memory was leaked. Can someone explain why?